# Laravel Supervisor "could not open file: artisan" error

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord

So I'm running supervisor in background in my production server to do two things:

1. php artisan queue:work
2. php artisan schedule:work

The problem is that queue work is working fine, but the schedule work throws "could not open file: artisan" error!

Here's my supervisor conf:

```
[program:influencer-queue-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php8.1 /home/scodus/domains/influencer.scodus.com/public_html/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=scodus
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/scodus/domains/influencer.scodus.com/queue.log

[program:influencer-schedule-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php8.1 /home/scodus/domains/influencer.scodus.com/public_html/artisan schedule:work
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=scodus
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/scodus/domains/influencer.scodus.com/schedule.log
```

Here's my Console/Kernel.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('inspire')->everyMinute()->sendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/inspire.log'));
        $schedule->command('order:revenue-pending-to-available')->everyMinute();
        $schedule->command('order:cancel-without-requirements')->everyMinute();
        $schedule->command('order:autocomplete-delivery-attempted-orders')->everyMinute();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because your `artisan` file does not exist or the path to the `artisan` file is incorrect.

In your supervisor config file, the command execution path does not seem to be correct

```
command=php8.1 /home/scodus/domains/influencer.scodus.com/public_html/artisan
```

Comment: But the queue:work works, just not the schedule:work! And they both have the same path!

Comment: Just checked in my local, it seems to be a `schedule:work` bug (or a desired behavior). You could change your command to `command=cd /home/scodus/domains/influencer.scodus.com/public_html && php8.1 artisan schedule:work`

Comment: Thanks man! You solution work! However I had to use bash script as it gave me error "command cd not found"!
i.e.
command=/bin/bash -c "cd /home/scodus/domains/influencer.scodus.com/public_html && php8.1 artisan schedule:work"

Comment: I had no idea for now. But you can try to put your commands into a script file, then change command to execute that script, like `command=/path/to/script/script.sh`